# Number of faces in n intersecting lines

Tags: graph-theory, alternative-proof, planar-graphs

Consider a set L consisting of n lines in the plane. No two of them
are parallel but many can pass through a single point. By drawing
these lines we create vertices (intersection points of the lines), edges
(parts of the lines between intersections and semiinfinite rays extending from the first and last intersections on a line to infinity), and faces
(connected parts of the plane after removing the lines from it).Prove that unless all the lines pass through a single point, there exist at most n faces bounded by 2 (semiinfinite) edges.

I have completed this proof in another way. But apparently, I am supposed to get a result that involves this expression, $e \ge 3f - n $. I have no idea where this inequality comes up in the proof nor how to use it. I got the inequality as a hint from the book. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suppose your other way goes somewhat like this?: If a ray is boundary to two such faces, then the opposite ray of that line cannot bound such a face.  By removing the line, we can apply induction (while taking care of the case that the removal leads to a single intersection point)

Comment: I don't think you can remove a ray without removing the entire line, given how the problem was stated.

Comment: You can prove it by induction. Or you can look at the whole configurations as  planar graphs, and try to use the relations (topological character) connecting v, e, f. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph

Comment: I recently found out that the expression is supposed to be 2e > 3f -n